# How to pass text with new line as parameter to a bat file?

Tags: parameters, batch-file, newline, command-prompt

If I pass text like this:

```
first line
second line
```

to a .bat file, it is taking the first line only as a parameter value.

How can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: How do you pass the text to the batch file? From an external program, from the command line, how do you insert the newline?

Answer (score 4):

It is nearly impossible to pass a newline within a batch file argument. It can be done, but I don't think anyone has developed a pragmatic way to properly read such a parameter within a batch file.

Your best bet is to define an environment variable that contains the two lines of text, including the newline. Then pass the name of the variable as an argument to the batch and then let the batch file access the value using delayed expansion.

test.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !%1!
```

From the command line:

```
>set multiLine=hello^
More?
More? world

>test multiLine
hello
world
```

For anyone interested, here is a discussion initiated by jeb concerning newlines in batch parameters: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1768

Answer (score 0):

You can access all parameters, but only if the batch files is started with `cmd /c`, ex. like a drag&drop action.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !cmdcmdline!
```

But if you start the batch file from the prompt, then this will not work as `cmdcmdline` contains only how the cmd.exe was started, in that case it's normally something like `"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"`.