# Report multi-line comment in batch file to TeamCity

Tags: batch-file, teamcity

I have a batch file which receives an input parameter containing a multi-line comment (stack trace) which I want to report to TeamCity. The code below works fine for single line comments and removes brackets and quotes from the message. The problem is that only the first line of multi-line messages are reported.

```
rem Try to remove line breaks (not working)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET message=%~1
set ^"message=!message:^

= !"

rem Remove square brackets and quotes
SET message=%message:[=%
SET message=%message:]=%
SET message=%message:'=%

rem Print message to console for TeamCity
echo ##teamcity[progressMessage '%message%']
```

Is there a way to remove all line breaks and replace them with spaces before the echo statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably out of luck: While it is possible to create multiline variables, it seems to be impossible to receive them via arguments in a batch file.

If it were a batch-to-batch call, you could store the multiline value in an environment variable and pass the name of the variable.

If you control in any way the calling application, you may consider replacing the newslines there, or probably better, have it call something else than batch file.

See also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866860/63733) and the [link](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1768) contained in the answer which discusses the problem of receiving multiline arguments in more detail.

By the way, your code to replace newlines works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there isn't a general solution.
But it could exists a solution for you!

It depends on the way your batch is called, if it's called through a new cmd instance you can use !cmdcmdline! to access the complete parameters even with linefeeds and also carriage return characters.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "message=!cmdcmdline!"
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"
set LF=^


REM ** Two empty lines are required
FOR %%L in ("!LF!") do set "message=!message:%%~L=\n!"
FOR %%C in ("!CR!") do set "message=!message:%%~C=\r!"
echo ##teamcity[progressMessage '!message!']
```

You can test it with invoke.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"
cmd /c test one!lf!two!CR!three
```

Comment: Still needs to delete the command line invokation (I get something like `##teamcity[progressMessage 'cmd \c test one\ntwo\rthree']`, but this is really cool! Glad I don't have to use it, though :-) +1 from me!

Comment: @marapet You are right, but this needs a bit knowledge about the invoke name. As it could be invoked by `cmd /c test.bat one-two-three` but it could also be `cmd /c test one-two-three` or even `cmd /c "/path with space/test" one-two-three`. So it's not easy to remove the head.